# How to make visual studio auto-save changes after delay like vscode?

Tags: visual-studio

I recently started to work with visual studio 2017. I am looking for making visual studio 2017 to auto-save after delay as what vscode does. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask for, but Visual Studio has [AutoRecover](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/208c6tcy.aspx) feature that can restore unsaved changes in case of a crash.

You can also [auto save files when Visual Studio loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574292/how-can-i-autosave-my-visual-studio-2015-files-when-it-loses-focus).