# Is there an autosave feature in Visual Studio 2017 to deal with its bugs and crashes?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2017

I used to deal with this when I was working with `Adobe AfterEffects`. It was (and maybe still is) so buggy that it could crash at any moment. So instead of fixing their buggy code-base their developers added a feature that would periodically auto-save all solution files into a separate (copy) folder. So after a crash you could recover some of your work. (Mine was set on auto-save every minute.)

So I've recently switched to using Visual Studio 2017 to develop my C++/MFC projects. (Before that I worked with somewhat older VS 2008 that used to crash very rarely.) But now VS2017 crashes pretty much every day. And if I forget to click save, it literally takes down last 10-15 minutes of my work, if not more.

*I tried reporting this to Microsoft (back in summer of 2018, 6 months ago.) Some of my reports were either closed right away when they needed more proof and I didn't have time to deal with their laziness to read my entire post, but some that were accepted are still open and were never fixed. So I'm done submitting bug reports through that portal.*

My only recourse at this point is to ask if there's an auto-save "feature" in VS2017, similar to what Adobe did to their AfterAffects?

---

*Anyone wants to crash it right now? Here's just one bug. Create new project -> Visual C++ -> MFC/ATL project -> MFC Application. Then go to Resource View -> Add Resource -> Accelerator. Then click on "None" where I pointed with an arrow:
[image]
Is your VS2017 still running after that?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make visual studio auto-save changes after delay like vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078068/how-to-make-visual-studio-auto-save-changes-after-delay-like-vscode)

Comment: @KenY-N: Auto-recover is a joke. It literally worked in 0% of the crashes I've experienced.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that bug with the accelerator too. I am not sure if it's worth the headache to report it. You have to edit the *.rc file manually. Or use VS2008 to make the *.rc code and copy to VS2017. I have found VS2017 is otherwise stable. Restarting your computer might fix other odd bugs.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing -- editing the .rc file manually in text editor. The problem is that I remember about it after I click there. (When it's too late and VS already crashed.) And it's just one bug of many. So I can't believe you find it stable. Also I've been using [Visual Studio solution cleaner](https://dennisbabkin.com/utilities/#VSSolutionCleaner) to clean up projects after being opened for a while when Intellisense gets borked up. But that won't clean up those code bugs though.

Comment: `10-15` minutes worth of work? I hit save literally after *every few statements* - whenever there is a *slight* pause in my hand movements. I don't even notice myself doing it now.

Comment: @Galik: well, I guess I should start doing it too.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a plugin in the market that does the job.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fluffyerug.Autosave2017

Comment: I have not enough reputation to comment on @abel 's answer, but it is worth mentioning. Thanks for noting there is a better plugin for this. I guess the one from fluffeyrug is getting outdated.

Answer (score 2):

"Auto Save File" extension has more installs and better reviews than the extension from fluffeyrug.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HangjitRai.AutoSaveFile